# change line in bash using regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, bash, command-line

I need to replace some text using linux command line:

i have some files:

```
-------------------
line 1
line 2,2
line 3_4
-------------------
```

i have a partial solution:

```
sed -i 's/line 1/my line 1/g' /my/file
```

this works but when i tried to replace line 2 and 3 it does not work. i get:

```
-------------------
line 1
my line 2,2
my line 3_4
-------------------
```

I need:

```
-------------------
line 1
my line 2
my line 3
-------------------
```

is there an easy way to use reg exp to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed 's/^ *\(line [0-9]\+\).\+$/my \1/' file
line 1
my line 2
my line 3
```

If you want inline editing of this file use:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^ *\(line [0-9]\+\).\+$/my \1/' file
```